# Wordpress Ninja Forms

Tags: jquery, wordpress, backbone.js, plugins, ninja-forms

I have a form which has been create with Wordpress Ninja Forms plugin.  The form will not submit - it "sticks" on processing.. and will not proceed. 
I have disabled other plugins, and tried a different theme to find the error. it still occurs.

This is what comes up in the Chrome Console:

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
>   /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 404 (Not Found) front-end.js:2 ERRORS: Not Found
>   front-end.js:2 Object front-end.js:2 Parse Error front-end.js:2
>   Notice: Error trying to reset grecaptcha. front-end.js:1 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined
>       at n.submitErrors (front-end.js:1)
>       at _ (backbone.min.js:1)
>       at m (backbone.min.js:1)
>       at f (backbone.min.js:1)
>       at u.Channel.u.trigger (backbone.min.js:1)
>       at Object.error (front-end.js:2)
>       at i (jquery.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:2)
>       at y (jquery.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)
>   [Link to Site](http://raf-bridging.co.za/)

Error Log:

```
[18/May/2017:19:58:36 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=nf_ajax_submit&security=f0abfd2858&formData=%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%7B%221%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%7D%2C%222%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A2%7D%2C%223%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%222222222222222%22%2C%22id%22%3A3%7D%2C%224%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A4%7D%2C%225%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22poop%40poop.com%22%2C%22id%22%3A5%7D%2C%226%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A6%7D%7D%2C%22settings%22%3A%7B%22objectType%22%3A%22Form+Setting%22%2C%22editActive%22%3Atrue%2C%22date_updated%22%3A%222017-05-18+07%3A23%3A58%22%2C%22show_title%22%3A%220%22%2C%22append_page%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ajax%22%3A%220%22%2C%22clear_complete%22%3A%221%22%2C%22hide_complete%22%3A0%2C%22logged_in%22%3A%220%22%2C%22not_logged_in_msg%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sub_limit_number%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sub_limit_msg%22%3A%22%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22last_sub%22%3A%221%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Application+Form%22%2C%22default_label_pos%22%3A%22above%22%2C%22wrapper_class%22%3A%22%22%2C%22element_class%22%3A%22%22%2C%22key%22%3A%22%22%2C%22add_submit%22%3A1%2C%22changeEmailErrorMsg%22%3A%22Please+enter+a+valid+email+address!%22%2C%22confirmFieldErrorMsg%22%3A%22These+fields+must+match!%22%2C%22fieldNumberNumMinError%22%3A%22Number+Min+Error%22%2C%22fieldNumberNumMaxError%22%3A%22Number+Max+Error%22%2C%22fieldNumberIncrementBy%22%3A%22Please+increment+by+%22%2C%22formErrorsCorrectErrors%22%3A%22Please+correct+errors+before+submitting+this+form.%22%2C%22validateRequiredField%22%3A%22This+is+a+required+field.%22%2C%22honeypotHoneypotError%22%3A%22Honeypot+Error%22%2C%22fieldsMarkedRequired%22%3A%22Fields+marked+with+an+%3Cspan+class%3D%5C%22ninja-forms-req-symbol%5C%22%3E*%3C%2Fspan%3E+are+required%22%2C%22currency%22%3A%22%22%2C%22calculations%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22drawerDisabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22ninjaForms%22%3A%22Ninja+Forms%22%2C%22fieldTextareaRTEInsertLink%22%3A%22Insert+Link%22%2C%22fieldTextareaRTEInsertMedia%22%3A%22Insert+Media%22%2C%22fieldTextareaRTESelectAFile%22%3A%22Select+a+file%22%2C%22fileUploadOldCodeFileUploadInProgress%22%3A%22File+Upload+in+Progress.%22%2C%22fileUploadOldCodeFileUpload%22%3A%22FILE+UPLOAD%22%2C%22currencySymbol%22%3A%22%26%2336%3B%22%2C%22thousands_sep%22%3A%22%2C%22%2C%22decimal_point%22%3A%22.%22%2C%22currency_symbol%22%3A%22%22%2C%22beforeForm%22%3A%22%22%2C%22beforeFields%22%3A%22%22%2C%22afterFields%22%3A%22%22%2C%22afterForm%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22extra%22%3A%7B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 11059 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"`

[18-May-2017 19:07:03 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'clarksty_wp134.wpcn_ninja_forms' doesn't exist for query SELECT * FROM wpcn_ninja_forms WHERE id = 1 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/minamaze/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/minamaze/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, vc_do_shortcode, WPBakeryShortCode->output, WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Row->content, WPBakeryShortCode->loadTemplate, include('/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_row.php'), wpb_js_remove_wpautop, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, vc_do_shortcode, WPBakeryShortCode->output, WPBakeryShortCode->content, WPBakeryShortCode->loadTemplate, include('/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_column.php'), wpb_js_remove_wpautop, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, ninja_forms_shortcode, ninja_forms_return_echo, call_user_func_array, ninja_forms_display_form, do_action('nf_before_display_loading'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, nf_29_update_form_settings_check, nf_29_update_form_settings
[18-May-2017 19:07:03 UTC] WordPress database error Column 'meta_value' cannot be null for query INSERT INTO `wpcn_nf_objectmeta` (`object_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (1, 'date_updated', NULL) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/minamaze/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/minamaze/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, vc_do_shortcode, WPBakeryShortCode->output, WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Row->content, WPBakeryShortCode->loadTemplate, include('/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_row.php'), wpb_js_remove_wpautop, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, vc_do_shortcode, WPBakeryShortCode->output, WPBakeryShortCode->content, WPBakeryShortCode->loadTemplate, include('/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_column.php'), wpb_js_remove_wpautop, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, call_user_func, ninja_forms_shortcode, ninja_forms_return_echo, call_user_func_array, ninja_forms_display_form, do_action('nf_before_display_loading'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, nf_29_update_form_settings_check, nf_29_update_form_settings, nf_update_object_meta
```

Comment: give us a link to the page with the error

Comment: http://raf-bridging.co.za/

Comment: Thats just a holding page

Comment: @PhillHealey   The form is located at http://raf-bridging.co.za/

Comment: Yes,and that shows a holding page, not the form.

Comment: @PhillHealey - The form is located at the bottom of the home page

Comment: Have you tried deleting the plugin then downloading and installing it again? You might have some corrupt files. Haave you checked your site ^ server logs for errors?

Comment: @PhillHealey I have deleted and reinstalled various versions of the plugin, The log shows :  POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://raf-bridging.co.za/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ninja-forms&form_id=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"

Comment: That's not an error from what I can see. Do you not have a seperate error log? Also, did you disable then delete the plugin. Then download a new copy, upload it, and activate it?

Comment: @PhillHealey disabled, deleted, then downloaded a new copy, uploaded and installed it..  have downloaded the full error log.  This line includes an error:  (added to post) too long for comment